# Bodyweight exercise for the 'v'-muscle in the lower abdomen

Tags: abdominals, bodyweight-exercises

What exercise can I do for developing the lowest abdominal muscles (colloquially named the V-muscles)?

I need something that's bodyweight and I am aware that I'd need to lose some weight until someone can see them.

Answer (score 5):

The 'v' shaped section at the lower abdominals is commonly called the ['Adonis belt' or 'Apollo's belt'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo%27s_belt) depending on who you speak with, however a common (although obsolete) anatomical term  for this feature is the 'iliac furrow'.

[image: Roman statue of Apollo from Wikimedia]

Unfortunately, the ability to show off an Apollo's belt is very genetic. Rather than being a muscle, its a combination of the location of your hips and certain ligaments in the lower abdomen. The common attribute to a lot of people who show an Adonis belt is low bodyfat, good core development and engaging in sports that involve rotational aspects at the waist - such as martial artists, swimmers, surfers and the like.

The primary ligament that gives the 'v' look is the [inguinal ligament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inguinal_ligament) that forms part of the femoral triangle which is what gives the 'v' look. The second major anatomical feature that help give this look is a prominent ['iliac crest'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliac_crest), being the large bony outcrop of the hips which is generally fixed in size and shape. What both of these anatomical features have in common are their connections to the [external obliques, with portions of the obliques joining with the hip at iliac crest and while "the aponeurosis of the external oblique muscle forms the inguinal ligament"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abdominal_external_oblique_muscle). As such, you can help stimulate growth in this area by targeting your obliques, however while ligaments can grow, unlike muscles this takes a significant amount of time.

As for which exercises, any [bodyweight exercises that adequately stress your obliques](http://www.exrx.net/Lists/ExList/WaistWt.html#anchor1944764) should work - examples include the [hanging side crunch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4oHT4olsaY), [windscreen wipers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X59_4RrU_aA) or [side planks](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Obliques/BWSideBridge.html). Other activities that I've seen suggested are martial arts training with a bag, both traditional boxing or a martial art with kicks will work as both require significant rotation force generated from the waist.

As JohnP points out the [transverse abdominus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_abdominal_muscle) also connects with the iliac crest and inguinal ligament in a similar fashion to the obliques. These are a deep abdominal muscle beneath both the internal and external obliques, and are difficult to target properly. The best way to target these is the [abdominal vacuum](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/TransverseAbdominus/AbdominalVacuum.html).

[image: A picture of an abdominal vacuum from EXRX.net]

Comment: Overall a good answer, however, the inguinal ligament does not connect with the obliques. Being a ligament, it's sole function is to connect bone to bone, in this case the spine of the ilium to the pubic bone. Also, the term "iliac furrow" is not really a current anatomical term. You also want to concentrate just as much (if not more) on the transverse abdominus than the obliques.

Comment: @JohnP I've corrected some parts but, while the origin and insert of the inguinal ligament is disputed, it currently shown that the obliques to form a section of them. I've corrected the bit about the iliac furrow which is an obsolete term. I've added a section on vacuums too.

Comment: Holy term-paper!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - Huh. You are correct. I either did not know (or had not remembered from classes) that part of the IL fused with the fibers of the lower TVA. I had thought there was no connection from muscle to ligament in the body. I am curious as to why you think the origin/insertion of the IL is disputed, however. Pubic tubercle to anterior superior iliac crest.